Python Error when installing packages, how do I work-around?
I am receiving the following error when I try to install any package using pip. I have Python 3.12 and pip 23.2.1.
>> pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org numpy

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy

I originally was getting an SSL error which prompted me to add the trustedhost, and I no longer get the certificate error. Does anyone have any ideas?

Is the date set correctly?

I'm not sure I understand - how would I set the date / how does that help with the error?

The date on your computer is used in validating the SSL certificate. That is why if you set the date to many years in the past, you'll see invalid SSL certificate errors even in your browser. I'm not sure how it'll help fix your specific error, but it's something to check since you had issues with the certificates

Do you have other version of python installed on your host?

Have you done a search for the package on pypi, just as a sanity check? Use pypi.org/search

@pho, I see. I do have the correct date on my pc

No other version of python @YuriGinsburg, and I have checked pypi
